# Reconhecimento de cores com switch/case

Tags: switch, case, cores, spritesheet

No meu código, estou fazendo um mapa em que se um *pixel* for de cor *x*, então o *sprite x* vai ser colocado nele, exemplo:

```
int pixelAtual = pixels[xx + (yy * map.getWidth())];
tiles[xx + (yy * WIDTH)] = new Floor_tile(xx*16, yy*16, Tile.TILE_FLOOR);

if(pixelAtual == 0xFF000000)

{
tiles[xx + (yy * WIDTH)] = new Floor_tile(xx*16, yy*16, Tile.TILE_FLOOR);
}
```

Entretanto, quero mudar a lógica do `if` e `else if` para `switch/case`. Como eu escreveria o código pra isso — usando os hexadecimais das cores para a verificação?

Answer (score 0):

Veja se é isto que precisa infelizmente não entendi bem qual sua dúvida se for apenas a utilização do switch segue abaixo sua conversão do if:

```
switch(pixelAtual)
{
    case 0xFF000000:
      tiles[xx + (yy * WIDTH)] = new Floor_tile(xx*16, yy*16, Tile.TILE_FLOOR);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso, brigado

Comment: Por nada, se foi resolvido não esquece de marcar a resposta.